# Trouble understanding computer fan wires

Tags: battery-operated, fan

I recently found a computer fan in my school electronics lab and I'd like to use it in reverse - make it spin the other way. The trouble is that I can't understand what wire does what, since the color codes aren't matching any I could find.

The wires are brown, green, black, and blue. I've expiremented some and found that the black is the ground, and I think that the blue is the V+.

Comment: Is there a part number printed somewhere?
Also making computer fans spin the other way is not as easy as rewiring.

Comment: It's unlikely you can reverse it from the wires alone, it takes a power supply, not an ESC. Besides, the blades won't be as effecient in the other direction.

Comment: Since it has 4 wires, it is not a simple motor with a fan attached to it. I have only seen some very old 2-wire fans that are like that and can be used in reverse. With modern fans like this it is **IMPOSSIBLE**. They have electronics inside that will only allow the fab to spin in one direction.

Comment: Unscrew and screw it back facing the other direction. Problem solve.

Comment: Indeed, these fans are symmetrical, you can just **mount** them in reverse to get reversed air flow.

Comment: It has been used previously in some project so the label was scrubbed off. It's screwed onto a piece of metal, but the screws look like someone drilled into their head - can't just flip it, the piece is in the way if I do.

Comment: Then remove the piece with a hacksaw, a side cutter, a file, a dremel, explosives, whatever ... OR go forth and find yourself a fan that hasn't been messed up. This problem can not be solved by swapping wires around.

Comment: I tried flipping the wires, but it didn't do anything - so that's what I concluded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a PWM controlled fan. You won't be able to reverse the fan spin electrically. I suggest you just mount it backwards.

From [here:](http://www.pavouk.org/hw/fan/en_fan4wire.html)
[image: pinout]

See: [fan details](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/rev1_2_public.pdf)

Comment: I understand my yellow wire is simply miscolored as brown, then.